# The pipelines in Gitlab fail due cache in gitlab-runner of type Docker Executor

Tags: jestjs, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been pushing branches at the project in Gitlab. And it is a project shared. Before, the pipelines were working correctly. Suddenly, anyone new branch or anyone push of the same branches begin to fail. Locally, it works fine. I want to recovery the behavior that it before had.

```
// .gitlab-ci.yml
variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: <info>
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <info>
  DB_HOST: <info>
  DB_PORT: <info>

cache:
  key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG

stages:
 - test
 - deploy

...
```

I was trying to clear the cache of the Gitlab-runner globally. Also, I tried setting a new cache in the branch, like in the jobs. But, this not work. I think that the problem is in the Gitlab-runner. 
Is there a manner to reset Gitlab-runner from .gitlab-ci.yml? How to declare a new Gitlab-runner from .gitlab-ci.yml? I can't manually clean the runner cache of the pipeline because I'm not the admin of the project.

Also,  I have pushed the branches in other projects, in clean projects. The pipeline runs successfully. The pipelines have tests that request to DB SQL through nodejs+jest+express+sequalize. And I'm getting errors of ETIMEDOUT.

I appreciate your help.